# PUT request not updating data in DB. Status 200OK

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I have an issue with PUT update request. Found this problem is quite common but none of the answers out in web seems to work. Basically in Postman I receive status 200OK and "success" if no error found but the data in db does not update.

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle").put((req,res) => {
    Article.update(
      {title:req.params.articleTitle},
      {$set:{title:req.body.title, content:req.body.content}},
      (err) => {
        if(!err) {
          res.send("success")
        };
      });
});
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried updateOne but it doesn't work neither. I'm very new to all this and surely not seeing something obvious. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `Article.updateOne`

Comment: @ŞahinErsever I did, it changes nothing at all. Still getting success in postman and does not update values in db.

Comment: What is the value of `req.params.articleTitle`? What is the `title` of the document you are trying to update?

Comment: You can update a document using any of the methods: `update`,`updateOne`, `findOneAndUpdate`, etc. These methods return a _result_ document with details about the update.

Comment: Is filter correct? it looks like it has spaces. there could be some formatting issues if you use it as path parameter. 

change it to query parameter. also better log title to understand more

Comment: @cedric I must admit, I am dumb. I need to thank you a lot for specifying what exactly I should log in consol. I have been told to check log but nobody told me what. I am new to coding and things like that are hard for me to spot. The problem was a letter capitalisation in db whilst I was querying lowercase... Thanks a lot!